# Changing a list of element from Selenium in Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a script that will retrieve a new email and place it on my clipboard everytime I run it.

The site I am scraping runs on a javascript application. I notice an iframe at the end of the website but the js app is outside of it. 
But I am unable to retrieve the attribute.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
[Finished in 5.8s with exit code 1]
```

In Python 3.6

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/user/Documents/docs/chromedriver')

url = driver.get('https://getnada.com')
element = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.address.what_to_copy')

print(element)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `element` to a list of elements:

```
 //driver.find_elements returns a list
element = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.address.what_to_copy')
```

Either you need to index your list to get the proper element:

```
element[0].getAttribute()
```

OR you need to use `.find_element` to select only one

Comment: Silly mistake on my part, thank you for your help Ryan

Comment: @mexitaw Anytime. I was glad to help